# Are zero loss tensor also backpropagated?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I was reading the paper [Training Region-based Object Detectors with Online Hard Example Mining](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03540.pdf) and one way of implementing online hard example mining would be to erase (multiply by zero) some elements of the loss tensor. However, in this paper the authors claim that this would be inefficient since current deep learning frameworks allocate memory and perform `backprop` even for 0 loss tensors. Unfortunately, the authors don't mention which frameworks do that and I'd like to know about `Tensorflow` and `PyTorch` in this regard.

Furthermore, if instead of multiplying the loss by zero I gathered only the slice I'm interested from the loss would that avoid back-propagating through the non-interesting RoIs? For example:

```
active_rois = tf.where(tf.not_equal(rois, 0)) # get the rois I care about
truth = tf.gather(truth, active_rois) # filter gt tensor
pred = tf.gather(pred, active_rois) # filter pred tensor
loss = compute_loss(truth, pred)
```

The excerpt from paper I mentioned earlier:

> The loss layer can compute loss for all RoIs, sort them based on this
>   loss to select hard RoIs,  and finally set the loss  of  all non-hard
>   RoIs  to 0 .   Though  straightforward, this implementation is
>   inefficient as the RoI network still allocates memory and performs
>   backward pass for all RoIs, even though most RoIs have 0 loss and
>   hence no gradient updates (a limitation of current deep learning
>   toolboxes).

Comment: Concerning the backprop part you can always mitigate the effect by using a "Sparse" optimizer such as LazyAdam in TF or SparseAdam in Pytorch, that perform sparse updates. It will however requires that you gather the value you are interested in (the non-hard roll) , and compute the loss only for these ones in order to take advantage of the sparse updates.

Comment: Just to summarize then: (1) The effect mentioned in the paper happens both in PyTorch and Tensorflow, right? (2) To mitigate it I can use a sparse optimizer and gather the slice I want to optimize from the loss (similar to my example?). Thanks

Comment: (1) If you implement it like he said "The loss layer can compute loss for all RoIs, sort them based on this loss to select hard RoIs, and finally set the loss of all non-hard RoIs to 0 ". I'll say yes. However I don't have experience with PyTorch, so maybe there is a way to implement that efficiently taking advantage of the Dynamic Graph (2) Yes.

Comment: @Eduardo, hi, do you have more knowledge about the questions now? 1. why the 0 loss will have no gradient update? 2. is there any difference between setting the non-interesting samples/loss to zero between remove the non-interesting samples directly?

Comment: Take a look at similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/51196502/14290244