# Tensorflow difference between tf.stop_gradient and feed variables to optimizer?

Tags: tensorflow, variables, optimization, gradient

I'm trying to train a model in **self-supervised learning**. The flow chart is something like the following:
[image]

Let's assume that `N1` is already trained and we want to train just `N2`. This is my current implementation:

```
x_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 1])
x_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 1])

s_t1 = tf.stop_gradient(N1(x_1))  # treat s_t1 as a constant
s_t2_pred = N2(s_t1)) 
s_t2 = tf.stop_gradient(N1(x_2))  # treat s_t2 as a constant

loss = some_loss_function(s_t2, s_t2_pred)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)
```

In this way, I should be optimizing only `N2`. What makes me confused is the fact that if I were to use the following code I would obtain very different results (much better than the above):

```
# treat everything as a variable:
s_t1 = N1(x_1)
s_t2_pred = N2(s_t1)
s_t2 = N1(x_2)

loss = some_loss_function(s_t2, s_t2_pred)
var_list = take_all_variables_in_N2()
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss, var_list)
```

I wonder what is the problem with the first implementation. What is exactly the behaviour of `tf.stop_gradient` (the documentation is a bit poor)? How does this differ from the second approach?

From a practical perspective in semi-supervised learning: what is the difference between the two? Which one is the correct approach?

Thank you :)

---

---

**I added a possible solution to the problem in the comments below. I would still be happy to receive any feedback from more experienced users and to share some opinions on the best approach to structure a self-supervised learning problem in tensorflow.**

Bye, G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a possible solution to my question and I'm posting it here, in case someone may find it useful.

Apparently, `tf.stop_gradients()` only stops the new gradients to be back-propagated through the layers, but: if we have a momentum term (e.g. when using Adam or RMSProp) the variables of such layers could still be updated due to some gradients cumulated in the past (contained in the momentum term). Let's have a look at the simple case of SGD + Momentum; the formula would be:

```
w1 = w0 - a*grad(loss) - b*v0
```

where `w1` and `w0` are the weights at time 0 and 1, `a` is the learning rate `v0` is the accumulated velocity (a function of the past gradients). Using `tf.stop_gradients()` is equivalent to multiplying the second term for zero. Then, the update rule becomes:

```
w1 = w0 - b*v0
```

e.g. we still have a momentum component that can update the weights.

A workaround to this problem would be to explicitly passing the variables to be updated to the optimizer. For example:

```
var_list = take_all_variables_in_N2()
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss, var_list)
```

---

**References:**

[1] http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/

[2] [Using stop_gradient with AdamOptimizer in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158399/using-stop-gradient-with-adamoptimizer-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Does it mean that I can use variables instead of stop_gradient? Or do I still need to use them together?

Comment: I believe that passing the variables to the optimiser should be enough. However, if you want to be 100% sure the framework is updating only the variables you want, I would use both (but it is probably redundant)! :)